# How to fix null value in Spring Mongo group aggregation?

Tags: spring, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

For this query

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        match(Criteria.where("userId").is(accountId)
                .and("processingDay").gte(startMillis).lte(endMillis)),
        sort(Sort.Direction.valueOf("ASC"), "x1"),
        sort(Sort.Direction.valueOf("ASC"),  "x2"),
        Aggregation.group("A", "state")
                .push(new BasicDBObject("x1", "$x1")
                        .append("x2", "$x2")
                        .append("A", "$A")
                ).as("XS"));
```

result is `[{"A":null, "XS":{"A":NOT_NULL,...}}]`, how to fill `A` value where it is null?

Comment: _"how to fill A value where it is null?"_: Fill with _what_ value?  What is a typical output without a `null`? Are you thinking of excluding the field `A`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `group("A", "state")` creates object like this:

```
"_id":{"A":"...", "state":"..."}
```

But, it expects (`Output.class`) the `A` field in the root document.

Just add the `$first` operator to add the 1<sup>st</sup> `A` value in the root document:

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("userId").is(accountId)
            .and("processingDay").gte(startMillis).lte(endMillis)),
    //sort(Sort.by(Direction.ASC, "x1", "x2")) // explicitly
    sort(Sort.by("x1", "x2")), //Default is ASC
    group("A", "state")
        .first("A").as("A")
        .push(new BasicDBObject("x1", "$x1")
                .append("x2", "$x2")
                .append("A", "$A")
        ).as("XS"));
```